# Finding out what user Apache is running as?

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to secure a file upload directory on my server as described beautifully here, but I have one problem before I can follow these instructions. I don't know what user Apache is running as.

I've found a suggestion that you can look in httpd.conf and there will be a "User" line, but there is no such line in my httpd.conf file, so I guess Apache is running as the default user. I can't find out what that is, though.

So, my question is (are):

- how do I find out what the default
  user is
- do I need to change the default user
- if the answer is yes and I change the
  default user by editing httpd.conf,
  is it likely to screw anything up?

Thanks!

Comment: why has this question been downvoted? Yes, it's been updated as it has been answered elswhere, but I see no need to down vote? It's a perfectly good question? Perhaps our down voter would care to add a constructive comment regarding this?

Comment: You might want to post that update as an answer, and accept it, as you are currently in the Unanswered queue.

Comment: +1 for being told off on StackOverflow; some users seem insistent on running off new users

Comment: Linked question does not exist any more

Comment: The next question: what to do because its one of two users, like `root` and `www-data`. How do you give the "right" Apache group a permission to access something?

Comment: The answers to this question are, for the most part, bizarre. Most of them just give an incomplete list of common users and suggest running `ps` to find which one (or more!) of them is running anything, irrespective of whether that user actually *is* Apache. Just do the obvious thing - `apachectl -S`, as suggested in 2 answers.

Answer (score 298):

`ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'` typically will show what apache is running as.

Usually you do not need to change the default user, "nobody" or "apache" are typically fine users.  As long as its not "root" ;)

*edit: more accurate command for catching apache binaries too*

Comment: Yup, or it'll be www-data on Ubuntu.

Comment: ...and Debian. :)

Comment: That command shows me a list of things, most from `apache` but 1 from `root` too.

Comment: lampp runs httpd as daemon user

Comment: @GruffTech, What about Windows Server?

Comment: I have 3 processes (`/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start`), one's user is `root` and the other two `www-data`. Should I be concerned?

Comment: @zundi, the service starts as root in order to do things like bind to reserved ports (e.g. 80 and 443). Then it starts whatever the configured number of processes are, to do the web-server work, and any other tasks, as the defined users. That way requests are being handled by non-privileged processes. You will notice the the parent ID (PPID) is the same for all of the other processes. That idea with be the PID for that one process running as root.

Comment: That solution is fine, just be aware that it will list also "root" and the user who running this command. To avoid this you can add " | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root" to this command like nowthatsamatt answered below.

Comment: If you get a list or you have doubts better check @nowthatsamatt answer.

Answer (score 69):

You can try the following command:

```
ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I love this answer, better (more generic) than the most upvoted answer. Thanks

Comment: CHECK THIS ANSWER instead more voted one.

Comment: You're litterally hidding lines from `root` user, which means that if apache is running as root, well, it doesnt show anything. Same for the current logged user.

Answer (score 56):

Use `apachectl -S`, which will show something Apache user and group, something like this:

```
User: name="_www" id=70
Group: name="_www" id=70
```

Comment: Thanks, on my mac i see that apache is running as '_www'.

Comment: This is a good answer, because it is the one command that tells you a lot more about your running web server and presents it in a comprehensive way.

Comment: Oddly, on the Mac, although it shows as '_www', you use 'www' without the underscore for various commands (notably chown). By the way, this varies according to version of MacOs/Apache/Apache package. It's '_www' on my macOs Big Sur with Apache 2.4.38 from MacPorts. It used to be 'staff' on older builds, and I think it's different if you use Homebrew.

Answer (score 15):

According to the [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1293508&p=8123364#post8123364), on Ubuntu the default user for apache2 is `www-data`.

Seen to be true on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy.

---

From [Lars Noodén](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=168643) on the above forum.

> To be sure what [the user] is really set to, check the actual configuration files.
>   The umbrella file, `apache2.conf` will have something like the following,
>
> ```
> User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
> Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
> ```
>
> That is a reference to environment variables set in `/etc/apache2/envvars`.
>   `mod_suexec` also allows scripts to be run as yet a different user and group.
>
> To find any virtual hosts, which may use alternate users, groups, or both, check the configurations.
>
> ```
> $ egrep "^User|^Group|^SuexecUserGroup" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
> ```

For Red Hat based distributions it would be (usually its user running httpd is `apache`):

```
$ egrep "^User|^Group|^SuexecUserGroup" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
```

Answer (score 12):

I know that this is an old post, but it is still listed as unanswered, so I will make a suggestion. If you can't find which user or group Apache is running as, perhaps try opening the httpd.conf file. There should be an entry there for "User" and "Group". Not only can you see which user Apache is supposed to be running as, but you can change it if you feel the need to do so.

Answer (score 11):

You can include a line of code in your PHP script:

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Comment: Watch out here, this shows the user that PHP runs under, not the Apache user. If using mod_php these are the same but if, as is now very common, you're using something else (like php_fpm) they can easily be different.

Answer (score 5):

This code will - more or less - alphabetically list all the non-root users running processes containing `apache` (or whose name contains `apache`)

```
ps aux | grep -v root | grep apache | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Comment: The list will probably include users who are running processes like 'grep apache', such as your fine self.

Answer (score 4):

- To find out the user, you can simply use `ps aux | grep apache` while it is running.
- You don't need to, but if Apache is running as root there are security issues.
- Thirdly, changing the user of Apache will change his rights to access some directories. You need to make sure that /var/www (or wherever you have your websites) is accessible to the new user and group.
  On the systems I have looked at, apache was always installed using apache:apache (or similar) as user and group, so it should probably already be set like that.

---

NOTE: This is the same answer I gave on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as/2509422#2509422).

Answer (score 3):

Or you can check the apache configuration file and look for the owner & group.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach, at least for Debian/Ubuntu-based distros, is to *use the same method Apache does to set its user and group: **source `/etc/apache2/envvars`***!

```
$ echo "$(source /etc/apache2/envvars && echo "$APACHE_RUN_GROUP")"
www-data
```

If you want to get fancy, you can suppress errors if the file is not found, and provide a default value:

```
$ apacheuser=$(
     source /fail/etc/apache2/envvars 2>/dev/null &&
     echo "$APACHE_RUN_GROUP" ||
     echo nobody  
)
$ echo "$apacheuser"
nobody
```

Answer (score 3):

I found most of the solutions offered here are system- or configuration- specific (in particular, most of the solutions do not work at all on MacOS) and a few rely on the user knowing where Apache's configuration files are in the first place...

So I cheat a bit and let Apache itself tell me what's what.

The simple command `apachectl -S` will tell you what you need to know about a running instance of Apache, and its results can be parsed fairly easily. Here's my solution, which I use at the top of a few `bash` scripts to determine a variety of things I might need at any given time...

```
# Store the results so we don't have to keep calling apachetl...
astatus=`apachectl -S`

# Now grab whatever you want from the result... 
HTTPD_ROOT_DIR=$(expr "`echo "$astatus" | grep ServerRoot`" : ".*\"\(.*\)\".*")
HTTPD_DOC_DIR=$(expr "`echo "$astatus" | grep \"Main DocumentRoot\" `" : ".*\"\(.*\)\".*")
HTTPD_USER=$(expr "`echo "$astatus" | grep \"User:.*name=\" `" : ".*\"\(.*\)\".*")
HTTPD_GROUP=$(expr "`echo "$astatus" | grep \"Group:.*name=\" `" : ".*\"\(.*\)\".*")
```

These values can then be used as such:

```
echo $HTTPD_ROOT_DIR // /etc/httpd
echo $HTTPD_DOC_DIR  // /var/www
echo $HTTPD_USER     // www-data
echo $HTTPD_GROUP    // www-data
```

Comment: You can use the operator `<<<` to pass a string as stdin to a process: `grep b <<<$'a\nb\nc\n'`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Noyo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509334/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as):

```
APACHE_USER=$(ps axho user,comm|grep -E "httpd|apache"|uniq|grep -v "root"|awk 'END {if ($1) print $1}')
```

And then:

```
echo $APACHE_USER
```

Comment: Get the user (ubuntu command-line): echo $APACHE_USER

Answer (score 1):

Use lsof and pass the port apache is listen to as an argument. See the USER column for the user appache is running as.

```
# lsof -i :80
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd     21058   root    4u  IPv6  74730      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     21111 www-data    4u  IPv6  74730      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd     24915 www-data    4u  IPv6  74730      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Comment: lsof might be slow when you have a few 100k open filehandles and/or a quite busy server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this command in [CakePHP docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#permissions).

```sh
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
```

Now `HTTPDUSER` holds the username of the user who runs the server, `echo $HTTPDUSER` in my case outputs `www-data` –using [rlerdorf/php7dev](https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use right now:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG 2>/dev/null |
sed -n '/^User/s/.*name="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```