# How to get the name of the apache user

Tags: apache-2.2, opensuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding out what user Apache is running as?](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as)

I use openSuse and I try to find out the name of the apache user. So I enter

```
vim /etc/passwd
```

in the terminal. Or

```
ps -a
```

Both don't have apache listed. I have mysql and other stuff but apache isn't mentioned.
Any ideas?

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your apache is running as user `wwwrun`

Comment: thanks and whats the group for that user?

Comment: Check with `groups wwwrun`.

Comment: On OpenSuSe it's done by following command: `grep -i "^user" /etc/apache2/uid.conf
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

or

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

The first column of the output is the user that is running the process.

Sample output from a CentOS system

```
apache    4173  0.0  0.6 239100  6720 ?        S    Aug04   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

and an Ubuntu system

```
www-data  3124  0.0  0.2   6452  2180 ?        S    Aug04   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

On CentOS apache is running as user `apache` and on Ubuntu it's running as `www-data`

Comment: the first column is named with root, so is root the apache user?

Comment: I edited my question. habe a look at the output

Comment: no output pal. You messed up the link!

Answer (score 1):

just see on httpd.conf (usually on /etc/httpd/conf/)
grep User httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

You sure have creative ways for finding stuff. :-)

I have not installed Apache in openSUSE, but my blind guess is that the user is not actually named `apache` but `httpd` instead. Or then you don't have Apache installed. Please, when asking, try to be more verbose and descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -i "^user" /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```